# Is my macbook pro display busted?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, macos

I have a mbp mid 2012 running on yosemite. Since this morning, my display is behaving weirdly. It seems to have bluish-greenish tint and I've tried deleting color profile, recalibrating it, rebooting into safe mode. But nothing works. I've also tried switching graphics card (between intel & nvidia) using gfxcardstatus but no change with my display's behavior.

Here is a sample screenshot of my mbp display
[image]

Any ideas what is wrong with it ?

Comment: have you already tried a NVRAM reset? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063

Comment: Please share your screen size and/or exact MBP model.  EDIT. Sorry mid 2012 with nvidia can only be a 15"

Comment: Does the screen look normal when it's turned off?

Comment: You asked for any ideas:  Looking at your photo, I would guess the hardware - such as a thin transparent layer of the display, between the touchable surface and the coloured elements in front of the backlight - has been damaged.  Of course I am commenting over two years after you wrote your question.  Did you make any progress between then and now?